# Grafana - Comparison chart to compare data from one source in multiple time periods

Tags: charts, comparison, grafana, monitoring

What I want is very obvious. I have one stream from the ELK stack and I want to get the response size of today's traffic and compare it with:

- One day before
- One week before
- One month before

Also, I have one sample to give you more insight about what I'm going to do in **Grafana**:

[image]

The source image is for Goole analytics but, I want to implement something similar in Grafana. I searched a lot and didn't find any proper answers.